# ASP.NET or jQuery UI control to display graphs (nodes with multiple parents)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, user-interface

I need to design a web page where users can run jobs and the some jobs are dependent on multiple jobs to finish. I need the users to be able to run the jobs as well see the dependencies for each job along with the more details about the job itself like the status, who ran it last, when it ran etc. if I display multiple dependencies as children rather than parents, I will have to duplicate that data somewhere else if other jobs are also dependent on this. Is there any UI control (ASP.NET/jQuery) that I can use to display this kind of data (graph, not a tree)? or is there an alternate way to display it using the existing controls (may be showing the master and detail views)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested grid http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/hierarchyserverside
also for any particular row or job details you can use popup or jquery dialog box.